# ¿Cómo puedo identificar y manajar los errores http en mi proyecto se strapi?

Tags: strapi

[2023-10-18 17:02:46.516] error: errorMessage
ValidationError: errorMessage
at handleYupError (/home/desarrollo/Documentos/Docker/Docker-strapi/web_backend_strapi/node_modules/@strapi/plugin-users-permissions/node_modules/@strapi/utils/dist/validators.js:86:11)
at /home/desarrollo/Documentos/Docker/Docker-strapi/web_backend_strapi/node_modules/@strapi/plugin-users-permissions/node_modules/@strapi/utils/dist/validators.js:98:13
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async Object.create (/home/desarrollo/Documentos/Docker/Docker-strapi/web_backend_strapi/node_modules/@strapi/plugin-users-permissions/server/controllers/content-manager-user.js:67:5)
at async policiesMiddleware (/home/desarrollo/Documentos/Docker/Docker-strapi/web_backend_strapi/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/dist/services/server/policy.js:16:9)
at async /home/desarrollo/Documentos/Docker/Docker-strapi/web_backend_strapi/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/dist/services/server/compose-endpoint.js:29:16
at async /home/desarrollo/Documentos/Docker/Docker-strapi/web_backend_strapi/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/dist/middlewares/powered-by.js:10:9
at async /home/desarrollo/Documentos/Docker/Docker-strapi/web_backend_strapi/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/dist/middlewares/body.js:51:17
at async /home/desarrollo/Documentos/Docker/Docker-strapi/web_backend_strapi/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/dist/middlewares/logger.js:7:9
at async /home/desarrollo/Documentos/Docker/Docker-strapi/web_backend_strapi/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/dist/middlewares/powered-by.js:10:9
at async cors (/home/desarrollo/Documentos/Docker/Docker-strapi/web_backend_strapi/node_modules/@koa/cors/index.js:107:16)
at async /home/desarrollo/Documentos/Docker/Docker-strapi/web_backend_strapi/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/dist/middlewares/errors.js:9:13
at async session (/home/desarrollo/Documentos/Docker/Docker-strapi/web_backend_strapi/node_modules/koa-session/index.js:41:7)[2023-10-18 17:02:46.516] error: errorMessage
ValidationError: errorMessage
at handleYupError (/home/desarrollo/Documentos/Docker/Docker-strapi/web_backend_strapi/node_modules/@strapi/plugin-users-permissions/node_modules/@strapi/utils/dist/validators.js:86:11)
at /home/desarrollo/Documentos/Docker/Docker-strapi/web_backend_strapi/node_modules/@strapi/plugin-users-permissions/node_modules/@strapi/utils/dist/validators.js:98:13
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async Object.create (/home/desarrollo/Documentos/Docker/Docker-strapi/web_backend_strapi/node_modules/@strapi/plugin-users-permissions/server/controllers/content-manager-user.js:67:5)
at async policiesMiddleware (/home/desarrollo/Documentos/Docker/Docker-strapi/web_backend_strapi/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/dist/services/server/policy.js:16:9)
at async /home/desarrollo/Documentos/Docker/Docker-strapi/web_backend_strapi/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/dist/services/server/compose-endpoint.js:29:16
at async /home/desarrollo/Documentos/Docker/Docker-strapi/web_backend_strapi/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/dist/middlewares/powered-by.js:10:9
at async /home/desarrollo/Documentos/Docker/Docker-strapi/web_backend_strapi/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/dist/middlewares/body.js:51:17
at async /home/desarrollo/Documentos/Docker/Docker-strapi/web_backend_strapi/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/dist/middlewares/logger.js:7:9
at async /home/desarrollo/Documentos/Docker/Docker-strapi/web_backend_strapi/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/dist/middlewares/powered-by.js:10:9
at async cors (/home/desarrollo/Documentos/Docker/Docker-strapi/web_backend_strapi/node_modules/@koa/cors/index.js:107:16)
at async /home/desarrollo/Documentos/Docker/Docker-strapi/web_backend_strapi/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/dist/middlewares/errors.js:9:13
at async session (/home/desarrollo/Documentos/Docker/Docker-strapi/web_backend_strapi/node_modules/koa-session/index.js:41:7).
La consola del servidor me muestra este mensaje de error.
Me gustaría poder manejarlo desde mi proyecto.